# Rendering new form for a nested Ruby on Rails Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

In my Ruby on Rails application, each group has_many :expenses. I have nested my routes, so expenses are entered only as child entities of their parent groups. Here's an excerpt from routes.rb.

```
resources :groups do
    resources :expenses
end
```

I cannot figure out how to render the 'new' action in the case of an expense not saving when it is submitted through /groups/:group_id/expenses/new. In my expenses_controller.rb, here is how the create action is defined:

```
def create
    @expense = Expense.new(params[:expense])
    @expense.group_id = params[:group_id]
    if @expense.save
      redirect_to group_expense_path(@expense.group.id, @expense.id)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Everything works fine if I satisty expense validation and @expense.save winds up working. However, when it fails and the code tries to render 'new' I get:

```
undefined method `expenses_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd408b1fd58>:0x007fd408f21ca8>
```

So, I am assuming I have something about my nested routing wrong. How do I return the user to the new form but still display to him/her through the flash[] params the errors with the data they originally attempted to submit?

Comment: can you add your view code please?

Comment: Sure. It's <%= form_for [@group, @expense], html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <% if @expense.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@expense.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this expense from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @expense.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %> ... form controls ... <%end%>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `@group` is not initialized

So in your controller just do

```
@expense = Expense.new(params[:expense])
@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
@expense.group_id = @group.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to explicitly specify the url for form_for in your view.

Something like…

```
<%= form_for @expense, :url => group_expenses_path(@group.id) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<%= form_for %>` you have used `@group` for url, because expenses belongs_to groups. But inside your create action in the controller you have not defined what is `@group`, so first you should define it as:

```
@expense = Expense.new(params[:expense])
@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
@expense.group_id = @group.id
```

Also I would suggest to use `respond_to` in your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @expense.save
    format.html { redirect_to group_expense_path(@group.id, @expense.id), :notice => "Any msg you want" }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
  end
end
```

All of these are in your create action inside the controller.
Also for different rendering methods look up: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html 
Hope this helps!